# Why does this recursive python function return None?

Tags: python, recursion

I am not understanding how recursion works. The base case runs last, and yet the return value is None. How come?

```
def simpleRecursion(myString) :
    print (myString);
    if len(myString) == 0 :
        # base case
        return "base";
    else : 
        # recursive step
        simpleRecursion(myString[1:])

result = simpleRecursion("abcdefg");
print(result);
```

Comment: You don't actually return in your `else` clause.

Comment: Neither of the answers explicitly says this, so in case you didn't know: whenever you fall off the end of a function without hitting a `return` statement, the function returns `None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns `None` because you only return a value if the length of the argument is `0`, i.e. the argument is an empty string. In the recursion `simpleRecursion(myString[1:])` may return a value, but you **never use it**. Thus, `simpleRecursion` does not return a value at all, unless the argument is an empty string. Replace `simpleRecursion(myString[1:])` with `return simpleRecursion(myString[1:])` to fix this.

Answer (score 4):

You have to explicitly return in your else clause, otherwise the return value will be lost:

```
else: 
    # recursive step
    return simpleRecursion(myString[1:])
```